# Power 12V air mattress pump from 5V powerbank

Tags: electrical, powertools

I would like to power 12V 32W air mattress pump from power bank. Power bank output is 5V and this is not enough (correct me if I'm wrong)

I see two ways:

1. Using DC-DC converter. I found one XL6009E1 in local shop. It is max
   10W. So, I think I need several of them connected parallel to
   power bank and pump. Will it work?
2. Use two power banks connected in serial way. In this case I suppose
   to get 10V. What if these power banks are different models?

Which method is better? Where I need to pay attention in both methods?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement SE. This isn't really the type of question that's on topic here.

Comment: Electrical Engineering SE might be the place.

Answer (score 1):

> **several [10W DC-DC converters] connected parallel to
>   power bank and [mattress? inflation?] pump. Will it work?**

That is the wrong way to approach the problem.

> **Use two power banks connected in serial way. In this case I suppose to get 10V. What if these power banks are different models?**

That is the wrong way to approach the problem.

---

I would purchase a single DC-DC converter with 12V output and a rating of more than 32W.

I would attach this to a single "powerbank" (i.e. battery) rated at least 40W+. For a 5V powerbank 40W+ is 8A+ so use thick wires!

Comment: I can't find converter from 5V to 12V with such power? What will happens if I will go in both workaround ways from theoretical point of view?

Comment: @vico - As RedGBrick has said the work arounds are not the way to do it. More bluntly do not do it. You should get off the idea of using a power bank anyway. These are meant for charging USB devices at typically 2A max. These things will not power the DC-DC converter even if you could find a suitable one. As RedGBrick has said such converter for a 5V input would require at least 8A input current at 5V. Get yourself a decent 12V sealed lead acid battery instead. A 12V 7AH battery should serve you well. No converters needed. Wall wart chargers for same available too.

Comment: You are asking the equivalent of how to melt steel with a lighter. It won't work as one of two things will happen first: 1) you'll run out of fuel, or 2) the entire thing will melt down in your hand trying to provide that much power.